# SQL efficiency. How should I setup my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am in the process of building a system to sort and make searchable a huge amount of data in the CSV format - X, Y, Z, Attributes (attributes are all separated by commas and I have them all in that one column for ease)

I have approximately 2gb of data in this format and I need to build a system where the user can specify and X,Y coordinate and find all points at that coordinate or within a set range. This need to be as fast as possible.

I can achieve this easily the old fashioned way and have it all in one table. I need advice on efficiency.

My current thoughts are:

1) Break it up into multiple grids (100m x 100m) and have a grid key in the table i.e X: 670.123 and Y: 540.009 would become grid_ID 670.540 and I could select using that. I think this would be slower as I'd still have to SELECT over a huge table.

2) Break it up into multiple tables based on a grid system (100m x 100m) to limit the data in each table. This is where I am currently leaning.

If anyone has ideas that would be better than this please let me know :)

Note: Probably not relevant but the app connecting to the SQL server will be written in VB.NET. Also, I'm not determined to use SQL - if there is a better way I'd rather use that.

EDIT: @juergen-d - this system is very much like a dictionary. The X and Y are the key and the attribute column is the value. I could split the columns but some data sources might have 10 attribute and others might have 1 attribute. Its easier to have it in one column.

@user2864740, zerkms  - there are a few million rows and I might need to do distance comparisons. This is a huge amount of data. I'm looking for a max search time of 3-4 seconds. I need to limit the data somehow

@zerkms - Spatial index!! Thank you!

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! Put every info in a seperate column. That makes it really fast too.

Comment: I would *avoid* a table-per-grid. That encodes information in the table schema and makes queries against such difficult - yech! The way to speed up queries is to *use indexes appropriately*; this also means that the data has to be correctly normalized or otherwise made sargable over some set of columns/data.

Comment: Just 2 words: spatial indexes

Comment: Be aware that one column of delimitated values for ease = bad performance for querying.  You might consider using geometry, special. or XML data types (along with proper indexing) to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Option 2 that you mention is just manual table partitioning and indexing. Don't break things into multiple tables to make them smaller - learn about indexes and partitioning. 'It's easier to have it in one column'? It's a little extra work to design your database properly upfront, but it much better to design it properly now and reap the benefits in your app. I'm talking about storing your attributes in a separate table with a foreign key to your X/Y table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two gigs of data can be searched super fast if proper indexing is applied. I would put all data in one table and create two secondary non-clustered indexes on x and y.

Comment: depending on the range of x and y, you could even map them to a single index.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, consider **Spatial Indexes**

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)